# How to compare strings by similarity without ignoring typos?

Tags: java, algorithm, comparison

I need to compare two strings by proximity, in case that the string.equals on the full string fails, I need to compare always the first name, and the middle and/or last name.

I already have find some comparison algorithm, but they all consider the misspelling on the result and I have to compare the exact input.

Examples:

> 1. Maria souza silva = Maria souza silva = ok
> 2. Maria souza silva = Maria silva = ok
> 3. Maria souza silva = Maria Carvalho = Nok
> 4. Maria souza silva = Ana souza silva = Nok
> 5. Maria de souza silva = Maria de = Nok
> 6. Maria de souza silva = Maria souza = OK

I`m trying something like this:

```
String name = "Maria da souza Silva";

String nameRequest = "Maria da Silva";

if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameRequest)){
    System.out.print("ok 0");
}

String[] names = name.split(" ");

int nameLenght = names.length-1;

if(nameRequest.startsWith(names[0])){
    System.out.println("ok 1, next");
} else {
    System.out.print("nok, stop");
}

if(nameRequest.endsWith(names[nameLenght])){
    System.out.print("ok 2");
}
```

The result is `ok 1, next` and `ok 2`.

The first and last name is OK, but I need to compare the middle name and ignore the ones like "de/da".

Comment: Can you provide examples of the behavior you want?  It isn't clear from your description.

Comment: Edited to give some examples

Comment: What should be the result of `Maria ana souza silva = Maria silva`? Of `Maria silva = Maria ana souza silva `? In what way do you want `de` or `da` treated differently than any other middle name?

Comment: Both should be ok. I always need to ignore `de` and `da`

Comment: So `De something else = something else`?

Comment: I accepted the answer from @ZGorlock, I made some adaptations and is working fine. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to use pure regex at first, and there is probably a way, but this code will produce the results you are looking for, using first and last, or first and middle, and ignoring de and da.

```
private void checkName(String target, String source) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<firstName>[^\\s]+)\\s((de|da)(\\s|$))?(?<otherName>.*)$");
    Matcher targetMatcher = pattern.matcher(target.trim().toLowerCase());
    Matcher sourceMatcher = pattern.matcher(source.trim().toLowerCase());
    if (!targetMatcher.matches() || !sourceMatcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Nok");
    }

    boolean ok = true;
    if (!sourceMatcher.group("firstName").equals(targetMatcher.group("firstName"))) {
        ok = false;
    } else {
        String[] otherSourceName = sourceMatcher.group("otherName").split("\\s");
        String[] otherTargetName = targetMatcher.group("otherName").split("\\s");

        int targetIndex = 0;
        for (String s : otherSourceName) {
            boolean hit = false;
            for (; targetIndex < otherTargetName.length; targetIndex++) {
                if (s.equals(otherTargetName[targetIndex])) {
                    hit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!hit) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ok ? "ok" : "Nok");
}
```

For your examples, the output is:

```
ok
ok
Nok
Nok
Nok
ok
```

Comment: pretty nice, thanks for the answer. I don't really know regex, can you help me a little bit more? What if I wanted to validate one more time the 'de/da', like "Maria da silva de souza"

Comment: just to justify my new request, if I try do compare "Maria da silva de souza" with "Maria de da" its printing OK but should be NOK

Comment: @ThiagoCruz Running the same code with "Maria da silva de souza" as the source and "Maria de da" as the target, or vice versa, the result is Nok for me. I am not sure if you are asking to validate an additional de/da, or ignore it. If you want to ignore it, you can add a check at the beginning of the second for loop, where if otherTargetName[targetIndex] is equal to de or da, then continue.

Comment: If you would like to see my code that is producing the results, or compare with yours, you can view it here: https://github.com/ZGorlock/Java-Sandbox/blob/master/StackOverflow/src/main/java/ThiagoCruz.java

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
String firstName = "maria";
String lastName = "silva";

String regex = ("^" + firstName + "([ ].*[ ]|[ ])" + lastName + "$");

System.out.println("maria de silva".matches(regex));
System.out.println("maria silva".matches(regex));
System.out.println("maria deb".matches(regex));
System.out.println("a silva".matches(regex));
System.out.println("mariasilva".matches(regex));
```

```
true
true
false
false
false
```

The regex will look for the first name in the beginning, the last name in the end of the string and in the middle either 2 spaces with any characters in between or just one space.

Comment: He wants to be able to match potentially with the first and middle name, instead of the first and last name only.